# Parsing JSON in AngularJS, avoiding reserved keywords

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parsing

```
var jsonURL='../../json/xx.json'

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('loaddata_traceroute', ['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http){

  $http.get(jsonURL).success(function(data) {
    $scope.datapoints_traceroute = data[0].abc[0].base-uri;
  })
}]);
```

I am trying to parse json through the code above. It works fine. However, if I try to parse deeper by adding ".base-uri", I can no longer parse it. I suspect that it is due to a reserved keyword because the error thrown in the console of Chrome is, "ReferenceError: uri is not defined"

Is there any other way to mitigate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use square brackets:

```
data[0].abc[0]['base-uri'];
```

This is a way to refer to properties that don't conform.

Answer (score -1):

Try..

```
$http.get(jsonURL).success(function(data) {
    $scope.datapoints_traceroute = data[0].abc[0]['base-uri'];
});
```

You can't access hyphenated parameter names directly without using square brackets and quoting the name.